# locate, updatedb & cron

Tags: 10.04, locate, updatedb

On a new EC2 Lucid AMI, I've tried:

```
$ locate include_prompt.sh
```

And got:

```
locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

I've created the locate database using `updatedb`, and it works fine.

Do I need to put `updatedb` in some cron file?

Is it invoked automatically? If not, what would be a reasonable interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original question was about Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).
One could read about updatedb being run daily here (link now disfunct)
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/updatedb.8.html

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) there is this file

```
/etc/cron.daily/plocate
```

installed by `plocate` package, which updates the database for the `locate` command. Did not find any online documentation about the automatic updating though.

Comment: Thanks, just found it on `/etc/cron.daily`

Comment: @Reinis: the link is not valid anymore

Comment: @ccpizza updated the answer for what it's worth :)